# Embeded controller in twig

Tags: symfony, controller, twig

Hello guys this is my controller :

```
   <?php

namespace ng\NearBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
   return $this->render('ngNearBundle:Welcome:index.html.twig', array('nom' => 'winzou'));
  }
  public function Header(){
  return $this->render('ngNearBundle:Welcome:nav.html.twig', array('nom' => 'winzou'));
  }
  public function Body(){
     return $this->render('ngNearBundle:Welcome:nav.html.twig', array('nom' => 'winzou'));
  }
}
```

this is the index twig :

```
{# src/ng/NearBundle/Resources/views/Welcome/index.html.twig #}
{{ render(controller('ngNearBundle:Welcome:Header')) }}
{{ render(controller('ngNearBundle:Welcome:Body')) }}
```

I have this error :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("The controller for URI "/_fragment" is not callable.") in ngNearBundle:Welcome:index.html.twig at line 2.
```

does anyone know the reason and how should I embed the controllers correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convention of the methods of the controller in Symfony2 provides that at the end of the method name there is "Action".

So by changing your methods:

```
public function HeaderAction(){
     return $this->render('ngNearBundle:Welcome:nav.html.twig', array('nom' => 'winzou'));
}
public function BodyAction(){
     return $this->render('ngNearBundle:Welcome:nav.html.twig', array('nom' => 'winzou'));
}
```

you'll get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

And take care of render, it use a lot of ressources ( internally its like a new request ), use twig include if possible

Comment: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

Take a quick look ;) Use include if you don't need code behind :)

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to render a controller in twig instead of a URL, you must enable the Symfony fragments configuration:

## app/config/config.yml

```
framework:
    # ...
    fragments: { path: /_fragment }
```